# comments_number display outside specified span

Tags: php, functions, comments

I want to display the number of comments a particular post has, so i thought i'd use comments_number, however when i use this the comment number gets printed outside of the span it's supposed to be contained within.

I tried using get_comments_number too, but that instead displays nothing at all.

The code below has been added to my functions.php amongst other code, but i just cannot get the comment number to display inside the span - it just prints at the top of the page.

```
$content .= '<p class="meta"><span class="date">'.$date.'</span><span class="comments">'. comments_number() .'</span></p>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comments_number` doesn't return the number of comments, it echos it out.

[As the codex clearly states](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number):

> Use [`get_comments_number()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) to retrieve the value.

Comment: Seems there was an issue with how i was initially using get_comments_number - but yes, it works like a charm.